# Reflection Matrix and Canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In [this](http://youtube.com/watch?v=z1XeKUOuLzc&t=346s) video a reflection matrix is build considering only the canonical basis.

What assure us that , if the canonical basis is correctly reflected throght a line, then every other point in the plane will be correctly reflected ??? What i mean is that: ok, with this matrix the canonical basis is correctly reflected, but maybe if i apply the matrix to some points, the result can be different from reflection, since i build the matrix considering only the canonical basis...

Comment: Since reflections are a linear transformation, if you know how the basis vectors transform you know how every vector transforms, as every vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know this , but maybe if i apply the matrix to some points, the result can be different from reflection, since i build the matrix considering only the canonical basis